Gmail Api sends 429 constantly while far below usage quota
I sync Gmail messages of users account with a Ruby on Rails app. I use the google-api-ruby-client, and more spcifically the gem "google-apis-gmail_v1".
I get very often 429 errors, which are caught, causing a restart of all the batch requests, and hence a lot of useless requests.
What does the code :
First : it lists "ids" of the Gmail messages with a "messages.list" call (cost : 5 unit of quota per call)
gmail = gmail_service(employee)
gmail.fetch_all(items: :messages) do |token|
    gmail.list_user_messages(
                    'me',
                    page_token: token,
                    quota_user: employee.id,
                    include_spam_trash: false
                )
end.each_slice(25) do |ids|
    sleep(0.5) # THROTTLING MANAGEMENT
    fetch_messages_from_ids(employee, ids.map(&:id))
    sleep(0.5)

For each 25 messages, it gets the message with a "message.get" call (cost : 5 units of quota per message = 125 units of quota by batch)
def fetch_messages_from_ids(employee, messages_ids)
    gmail.batch do |gmail|
        messages_ids.each do |id|
            gmail.get_user_message(
                'me',
                id,
                quota_user: employee.id,
                format: 'metadata',
                fields: 'id, history_id, label_ids, payload, size_estimate'
                ) do |result, err|
                    # Manage API answers
            end
        end
    end
end

I regularly (several times during a sync for an employee) get 429 errors.
I checked the Gmail API documentation.
Max quota unit consumed by second of my code : 5 (message.list) + 25 * 5 (25 messages.get in batch) = 130 units which is far under the 250 limit explained in Gmail API doc : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota
What i tried :

Reduced to a batch of 25 (instead of 50 initially)
Went to "batch" request as suggested in the Gmail Doc
Added two "sleep" to be sure these calls are done in more than a second

Exponential backoff seems to be an issue in batch request : if one call sends back a 429, then the whole batch of 25 request is sent. That's why i would like to find a better solution than using only the gem exponential backoff.

Don't bother batching it causes to many issues

Can you provide the actual error? BTW while I am not familiar with the result set size of gmail.fetch_all(items: :messages) it appears that the quota hit for this will be n * 5, where n is number of tokens for the iterative block, because the block calls list_user_messages. So for example if gmail.fetch_all(items: :messages) returns 50 tokens you have already hit the 250 quota depending on how fast those requests can process. This is then compounded by the 25 * 5 for the get_user_message call.

The problem is when you try and use batch it's sending all of the requests at the same time they're all hitting the server at the same time this will likely give you issues with the quota running over it's best not to use Batch and if you are going to use batch only send about five at one time.
